# Elementos duplicados en un array de objetos (js)

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente detalle, del siguiente array necesito crear dos array´s:
1.- con elementos correctos
2.- Elementos incorrectos:
.- Que la curp este duplida
.- Que la curp este vacia
.- Que el number este duplicado
.- Que el number este vacio

El codigo que tengo Me regresa todos los items del array no hace el filtro

```js
 this.array = [
        {nombre:'Prueba', apellido:'Prueba', materno:'Prueba', noEmpleado:'G001', number:'123456', curp:'PEFGG859V'},
        {nombre:'Prueba', apellido:'Prueba', materno:'Prueba', noEmpleado:'G002', number:'123594', curp:''},
        {nombre:'Prueba', apellido:'Prueba', materno:'Prueba', noEmpleado:'G003', number:'024587', curp:'PEFGG859V'},
        {nombre:'Prueba', apellido:'Prueba', materno:'Prueba', noEmpleado:'G001', number:'123456', curp:'PEFGG8FTT'},
       
    ];
```

```js
tieneDuplicados(array, propiedad) {
        const valoresUnicos = new Set();
        return array.some(objeto => {
          const propiedadValor = objeto[propiedad] || '';
          console.log('propiedadValor', propiedadValor)
          if (valoresUnicos.has(propiedadValor)) {
            return true;
          }
          valoresUnicos.add(propiedadValor);
          return false;
        });
      }
      
      
      async _validateData(){
        const curpsDuplicados = this.array.filter(objeto => this.tieneDuplicados2(this.array, 'curp') && objeto.curp);
        console.log('Objetos con CURP duplicado:', curpsDuplicados);

    }
```

Comment: Conoces la clase `Set` y la función `filter`? Si la respuesta es no, por favor investigalo.

Comment: tengo el siguiente codigo pero solo me regresa el primer elemento que encuentra creo es por el findIndex
duplicateItems() {
     const curpDuplicados = this.obtenerDuplicados(this.array, 'curp');
        console.log('Curp duplicados:', curpDuplicados);
    }

    obtenerDuplicados(arr, propiedad) {
        const duplicados = arr.filter((item, index, array) => {
            return array.findIndex(t => t[propiedad] === item[propiedad]) !== index;
          });
        return duplicados;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu validación es:

- curp exista
- number exista
- curp unico
- number unico

La función que hace esto es:

```
const validacion = a => a.curp && a.number && !array.some(b=> b!=a && (a.curp===b.curp || a.number===b.number));
```

Debes notar que la función `some` comparamos el item consigo mismo `a!=b` porque obviamente un item será igual a si mismo

Luego para traer los validos haces un `filter` para los que cumplan la condición y otro para los que no

```js
this.array = [
{nombre:'Prueba', apellido:'Prueba', materno:'Prueba', noEmpleado:'G001', number:'123456', curp:'PEFGG859V'},
{nombre:'Prueba', apellido:'Prueba', materno:'Prueba', noEmpleado:'G002', number:'123594', curp:''},
{nombre:'Prueba', apellido:'Prueba', materno:'Prueba', noEmpleado:'G003', number:'024587', curp:'PEFGG859V'},
{nombre:'Prueba', apellido:'Prueba', materno:'Prueba', noEmpleado:'G001', number:'0000', curp:'PEFGG8FTT'}
];

const validacion = a => a.curp && a.number && !array.some(b=> b!=a && (a.curp===b.curp || a.number===b.number));

const validos = array.filter(validacion);
const invalidos = array.filter(a=>!validacion(a));


console.log(validos);
console.log(invalidos);
```

---

Realizar 2 `filter` es algo ineficiente, quizás quieras todos en un solo ciclo

```js
this.array = [
{nombre:'Prueba', apellido:'Prueba', materno:'Prueba', noEmpleado:'G001', number:'123456', curp:'PEFGG859V'},
{nombre:'Prueba', apellido:'Prueba', materno:'Prueba', noEmpleado:'G002', number:'123594', curp:''},
{nombre:'Prueba', apellido:'Prueba', materno:'Prueba', noEmpleado:'G003', number:'024587', curp:'PEFGG859V'},
{nombre:'Prueba', apellido:'Prueba', materno:'Prueba', noEmpleado:'G001', number:'0000', curp:'PEFGG8FTT'}
];

function extraer(arr, fn){
   const validos = [];
   const invalidos = [];
   
   for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
     if( fn(arr[i]) ) {
        validos.push(arr[i]);
     }
     else{
        invalidos.push(arr[i]);
     }
   }
   return {
     validos: validos,
     invalidos: invalidos
   }
}

const validacion = a => a.curp && a.number && !array.some(b=> b!=a && (a.curp===b.curp || a.number===b.number));

const resultado= extraer(array, validacion);

console.log(resultado);
```